# Common Lisp Code Freezes or Needs to Be Optimized

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, lisp, common-lisp

I am currently working on some problems from Project Euler as part of my Common Lisp learning routine. I shall not mention which problem it is in keeping with the spirit of that site.

The issue I am having is that my code works for small inputs but freezes for large inputs. Specifically, it freezes for the same order of magnitude that is needed to obtain the answer, but runs successfully for the order of magnitude below that one.

The problem is described as follows: Given a set of digits, form all possible permutations of those digits, then sort the results numerically and pick nth member of the resulting set.

I would run the code below as follows.

For instance, if I wanted to obtain the 3rd permutation of digits `(1, 2, 3)`, I would make the call:

`CL-USER> (number-permutations '(1 2 3) 3)
213`

Another example is:

`CL-USER> (number-permutations '(0 1 2 3 5) 100)
50231`

The code works for this:

`CL-USER> (number-permutations '(0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8) 100)
1283675`

But freezes (or takes too long) for this call:

`CL-USER> (number-permutations '(0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9) 1000000)`

My questions is two-fold. What am I doing inefficiently that causes the calculation to take so long? Am I running into some limitation of the Lisp implementation (SBCL)? What can be done to get the calculation to finish in reasonable time?

Code:

```
;;; How to make permutations of a list
;;;
;;;   all permutations of a list L is:
;;;   for each element E in L:
;;;   that element prepended to all permutations of [ L with E removed ]
(defun permutation (digits)
  ;if the list is null or empty, return NIL
  (cond ((null digits) nil)
    ;if the list consists of one element, return the list of one element
    ((null (cdr digits)) (list digits))
    ; cycle through every element in list and append            
        ; that element to all permutations of a list of elements
    ; with the current element removed
    (t (loop for element in digits
          append (mapcar (lambda (l) (cons element l))
                 (permutation (remove element digits)))))))

(defun list-to-number (list)
  (loop for item in list for i from (- (list-length list) 1) downto 0
        summing (* (expt 10 i) item)))

(defun number-permutations (digits n)
  (car (nthcdr (- n 1)
         (sort (loop for item in (permutation digits)
                     collecting (list-to-number item))
               #'<))))
```

Comment: The number of permutations of `n` digits is `n!` so if, as you write (though my LISP is rusty and I haven't checked), your code forms all permutations then picks the `k`-th, it's no surprise that your processor collapses even when `n` is, apparently, quite small.  Are you sure the problem statement requires you to form the list of all permutations ?  Usually that problem is solved by finding the `k`-th permutation **without** finding all the others -- it's a test of your cunning, not of your processor's potency.

Comment: No, I am not sure. What I described was my understanding of the problem, which was probably marred by my thinking about how to solve it. You are probably correct about the need to be more cunning :)

Comment: I think I solved this using an algorithm found here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/AllPerm.shtml Over at CodeReview you can find my initial attempt and some very valuable comments on coding style and efficiency.

Comment: And another thing, after a closer look: OP's last test case seems to look for the `1,000,000`-th permutation of a set of `9` elements.  A lollipop for the first person to see why this might cause even the smartest algorithm to fail ...

Comment: Are you saying that 9! = 578880 < 1000000 ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `9! == 362880 < 10^6`.  (I used Mathematica to calculate `9!`, I guess your computation may be right, but in either case the inequality holds.)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment by [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark), so this question can be closed:

<s>***What am I doing inefficiently that causes the calculation to take so long?***

You do `n!` computations, `n` being a number of digits. With `1000000!` is roughly equal to 8.26×10<sup>5565708</sup> (see [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-factorial-of-1-000-000) for a nice explanation), so no wonder you computer can't handle it ;)</s>

***Am I running into some limitation of the Lisp implementation (SBCL)?***
Maybe, but your RAM is most likely the first thing to fail.

***What can be done to get the calculation to finish in reasonable time?***
Do another calculation. The point of the Project Euler exercises is usually to find a smart way to solve a problem, not to brute-force it.

Good luck!

Comment: To be fair to OP his (?) question does not seek to find `1000000!` permutations, but the `1000000`-th out of `9!` permutations.  Which raises another matter.

Comment: Right. My bad :/